# In org.json, how to do getString(), getBoolean() on a value of a key by first checking if it exists, without writing 'has' code to avoid exception

Tags: java, org.json

If a key does not exist, on doing get, will throw exception. Would like to avoid writing `if jsonObject.has("key"), if true, then jsonObject.get("key")` for each get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `opt*()` methods. Those that can return `null`, will return `null`, and others retrun a reasonable default value (or take a `defaultValue` parameter).